# ROS support for iRobot Create 2?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I just got an iRobot Create 2, see the link http://www.irobot.com/About-iRobot/STEM/Create-2.aspx

I tried to use ROS on it; soon, I find it is not that straightforward. Here are what I did so far. I installed ROS Indigo on a virtual machine with Ubuntu 14.04. Then, I looked for the package related to this iRobot Create 2 on the ROS.org, this is what I found http://www.ros.org/browse/search.php?distro=indigo&q=iRobot

Then, I installed the create_driver in my Indigo ROS. I think this driver is for iRobot Create not iRobot Create 2. Here, I want to ask for help. Does anyone here have some experience on how to make iRobot Create 2 move via ROS Indigo? Thanks! If you are interested or also stuck as me, we may team up to figure this out.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209391/ros-support-for-irobot-create-2?/) by [intelife_robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/22457/intelife_robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-05-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [luc](https://answers.ros.org/users/18958/luc/) on 2015-08-05**:
Feel free to check here from time to time:
https://github.com/lucbettaieb/create_2_drivers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

we have a working ros indigo node for the Create2.
https://github.com/MirkoFerrati/irobotcreate2ros

You will also find a joystick demo that allows you to move the robot via teleoperation.
We are still missing some features, but you should be able to move, use the LCD screen and read sensors and odometry out of the box!

Bye,
Mirko

---

Originally posted by [mirko.ferrati](https://answers.ros.org/users/24365/mirko.ferrati/) with karma: 16 on 2015-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mario](https://answers.ros.org/users/25757/mario/) on 2016-01-27**:
Miko, I see that your source code have  directory called gazebo
What do you use gazebo for?

**Comment by [mirko.ferrati](https://answers.ros.org/users/24365/mirko.ferrati/) on 2016-01-28**:
In the package we also provide a urdf model of the irobotcreate, inside the folders model and gazebo you can find the xacro files, while in the iRobot folder you can find the urdf.